# navigation will terminate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

does anyone know how I can call a notification similar to

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)notification
```

which is when app terminate, but what I want is when I drill up a navigation view.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the simplest approach here is to implement UINavigationControllerDelegate, set your class as the delegate for your UINavigationController, and use

```
-(void)navigationController:willShowViewController:animated:
```

to track changes.  You'll have to write some logic to figure out if you've just navigated up or down.

Answer (score 0):

For example, in your delegate...

`-(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)aController

willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController

animated:(BOOL)animated

{`
`if( [aViewController isKindOfClass:[MyCustomViewController class]])

{

//ive just popped or pushed the MyCustomViewController instance

//do something.

}

}`